# Google fit API: calories expended available for past days but not today, although activities present for today

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Following is the code that fetches calories for today:

```
    Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    long startTime = date.getTimeInMillis();

    date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    long endTime = date.getTimeInMillis();


    String calories;
    DataReadRequest dataReadRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder().read(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED).
            setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();
    Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(App.gClient, dataReadRequest).setResultCallback(
            new ResolvingResultCallbacks<DataReadResult>(this.getActivity(), 0) {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
                    String calories;

                    DataSet dataSet = dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED);
                    if (dataSet != null) {
                        List<DataPoint> dataPoint = dataSet.getDataPoints();
                        if (!dataPoint.isEmpty()) {
                            calories = dataPoint.get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).toString();
                            txtCalories.setText(calories);
                        }
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onUnresolvableFailure(Status status) {

                }
            });
```

When I set startDate=1, I am able to see the calorie count. However for today, there is no count.
Start time is 12 midnight of today and End time is 11:59 PM today.

Answer (score 0):

Today's day is not complete. Hence, I believe the end time would be giving an error. Instead you should set endtime as `Math.min(System.getCurrentMillis(), date.getTimeInMillis();)`